# packer vcenter integration for remote build

Tags: packer, vcenter

How can I get packer to build a remote build on a vcenter server?

I have it already running on an ESXi server but now want to migrate to center. vCenter does allow to work just like ESXi server when remote login via ssh is enabled, but I thought that vCenter should provide some better APIs. Note, that remote building of the image is mandatory, i.e. I can't use the post processing step of https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/vsphere.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the building via the vSphere API is not yet supported. But it's in the works, you should track and test PR [#4882](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/pull/4882)

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/pull/4882 is the correct link. Thanks.